# Launch PL/SQL script from batch file (with arguments)

Tags: batch-file, plsql

I'm strugling at passing arguments to a PL/SQL script from a Windows .bat file.

Here is the content of the batch file :

```
@echo off
set mName = "test"
exit | sqlplus <connection_string> @test.sql %mName%
pause
```

And here is the content of test.sql :

```
set verify off
set serveroutput on size unlimited
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('&&1');
END;
/
```

I would expect to see "test" appearing in the shell but instead, I get the following message :

```
Enter value for 1:
SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces around your `=` sign. Here's my working batch file:

```
@echo off
set mName="test"
exit | sqlplus <connection_string> @test.sql %mName%
pause
```

Also note that you can use the `-L` option on sqlplus for batch jobs:

> `-L`  Attempts to log on just once, instead of reprompting on error.

Comment: What the heck, I would never have found this by myself... Thanks man !