# I want to pass a variable argument to external SQL file (PL/SQL with SQL*Plus)

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have search this forum and via google for an answer for my question, but I can't find a specific answer for my challenge. That is why I am asking it here to hope to receive an answer from one of you guys.

I want to work with multiple SQL files, whereas one SQL file is the control file that executes the other SQL files with parameters.
That file is called: startup.sql

I have a table with all my values (don't mind the names of the columns, I changed them for my post).

```
create table control (
  S varchar2(15) not null,
  N varchar2(25 char) not null, 
  B varchar2(25 char) not null, 
  Acheck varchar2(25 char) not null, 
  Adcheck varchar2(25) not null, 
  Blu varchar2(25) not null,
  ADB varchar2(25)
)
```

Where one of the following is inserted (there are more entries, but one is enough to show you the way of working):

```
    insert into control (S,N,B,Acheck,Adcheck,Blu,ADB)
       values('Test','B','J','J','N','N', '');
```

My control file looks like:

```
set escape on
set serveroutput on
SET DEFINE ON

declare
  cursor c_lees_control is
    select S, N, B, Acheck, Adcheck, Blu, ADB
  from control

  v_s           varchar2(30);
  v_b           varchar2(30);
  v_blu     varchar2(30);

begin

  for r_lees_control in c_lees_control
  loop
    v_s := r_lees_control.S;
    v_b := r_lees_control.B;
    v_blu := r_lees_control.Blu;

    if v_b = 'J' then
      --Also tried this.
      --@C:/Temp/uitvoer.sql $v_s $v_blu
      @C:/Temp/uitvoer.sql %v_s% %v_blu%
end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

In my uitvoer.sql I have a variable like this:

```
    variable_s := '&&1';
    variable_blu := '&&2';
```

Now the following is happening.
I start SQL*Plus (with all my credentials) and I start my control file (control.sql).
In the output of SQL*Plus the following is stated:

```
old 89:        s = '&&1';
new 89:        s = '%v_s%';
old 128:       b_lu := '&&2';
new 128:       b_lu := '%v_blu%';
```

I was expecting the following:

```
old 89:        s = '&&1';
new 89:        s = 'Test';
old 128:       b_lu := '&&2';
new 128:       b_lu := 'J';
```

Why are my variables in the control file not parsed correctly to the new SQL file?

I also found the following posts:
[How do you pass an argument to a PL/SQL block within a sql file called using START in sqlplus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558929/how-do-you-pass-an-argument-to-a-pl-sql-block-within-a-sql-file-called-using-sta) / [Launch PL/SQL script from batch file (with arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496311/launch-pl-sql-script-from-batch-file-with-arguments)
It looks like my challenge, but I am not calling from an batchfile but from an sql file.

I hope someone can help me. If something is unclear, I can try to explain it a bit more.

Comment: Why do you want to store your code in external files, rather than in the database?

Comment: To make it not database dependant. I use my sql files on different databases.
I have one file that is creating my database structure, so it is the same everytime I need it. Also the databases are in managed by other parties and can do a role-back whenever they want.

Comment: I also tried that, that has the same effect.

I have one controle file that is checking what files are nescessary to run. I have 6 external files. That all use the same variables, but they check different options.

Comment: @JeroenMulder - what you've shown shouldn't run at all; are you really enclosing the values in quotes in the call from the control script, e.g. `'%v_s%'` and (in Nicholas' version) `'v_s'`? You also can't call an external file from PL/SQL; the contents of `uitvoer.sql` are being parsed as part of the block, so `v_s` is going to be treated as a variable in the included code - you don't need to treat it as a substitution variable at all?

Comment: @AlexPoole No that is just the problem, it is not running at all. I am not enclosing the values in quotes. Because if I do that, it is indeed sending it as text. And it should send the value within the variable. I think it does not parse the variable correctly.

Comment: @AlexPoole The idea is that the value of v_s is being defined in the control file and the value of v_s is being send to 'uitvoer.sql'.
I will add the example, to show it. And I am going to try to explain it a bit better.

Comment: But it isn't being 'sent' anywhere; the `@` is including the contents of that file within the PL/SQL block, at parse time. `v_s` doesn't have a value until run time. (A marginal, but important, difference with an anonymous block).

Comment: Actually you just helped me to get in the right direction. I was thinking this totally wrong. I now use the variable I send from the control file in 'uitvoer.sql'. So in 'uitvoer.sql' I now use v_s as it is. I did not know that was possible. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@` is a [SQL*Plus command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref428), it has no meaning in PL/SQL. Your script is being included within the PL/SQL block at parse time, which you can see if you [`list`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve028.htm) the code in the buffer. The variables declared in your control block are available to the 'included' code directly, without needing substitution.

As an example, if `uitvoer.sql` just contains:

```
dbms_output.put_line(v_s);
```

Then this control script:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  v_s varchar2(10) := 'Test';
begin
  @uitvoer.sql
end;
/

list
```

Produces:

```
Test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

  1  declare
  2    v_s varchar2(10) := 'Test';
  3  begin
  4  dbms_output.put_line(v_s);
  5* end;
```

The PL/SQL block in the buffer has the included code, *not* a reference to `uitvoer.sql`. But the included code worked because it referred to a variable from the control script which was still in-scope.

---

If you want to allow for the control variables having different names, allowing `uitvoer.sql` to be called more flexibly perhaps, then you can still use substitution variables, but you're still substituting the variable name, not its value. For example, with this `uitvoer.sql` (note that the substitution variable assginment does **not** have quotes around it):

```
declare
  variable_s varchar2(10);
begin
  variable_s := &&1;
  dbms_output.put_line(variable_s);
end;
```

And your control script passing the variable name:

```
declare
  v_s varchar2(10) := 'Test';
begin
  @uitvoer.sql v_s
end;
/
```

You see:

```
old   7:   variable_s := &&1;
new   7:   variable_s := v_s;
Test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

  1  declare
  2    v_s varchar2(10) := 'Test';
  3  begin
  4  declare
  5    variable_s varchar2(10);
  6  begin
  7    variable_s := &&1;
  8    dbms_output.put_line(variable_s);
  9  end;
 10* end;
```