# how to write a batch file, which runs a PL/SQL block, to tell me many records are inserted/deleted/etc. in a log file?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, ddl, dml

I have created two batch files to run two separate .sql file in Windows Task Scheduler. The batch file for both looks like this:

```
sqlplus userid/password@database @C:\XXX.sql>>C:\output.log
echo commit; | userid/password@database
```

The first .sql file (SQL1) is a PL/SQL block like this:

```
SET SERVEROUT ON
DECLARE
 ....
BEGIN
IF ...
 ....
ELSE  
@D:\DM_FIX.sql;
END IF
END
```

The DM_FIX.sql file is to insert a bunch of records into a table, and it starts with the INSERT command.

The second.sql file is not a block file. It's doing a bunch of DDL/DML comand. the file looks like below:

```
Truncate Table YYY
Reuse Storage;
Commit;

Insert into Table YYY
Select ... from
Commit;

Delete from Table YYY
where ...
Commit;
```

When I run the second .sql file, I get an output that indicates "The table has been truncated; #### records are inserted; #### records are deleted..."

But when I run the first, although the PL/SQL procedure is executed successfully, I don't get a line saying how many records are inserted, and I'm trying to figure out a way to do it.

Does any one know what could be the trick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Revised Answer**

As @Alex Poole helpfully pointed out, you can use the `@` nomenclature in a PL/SQL block from SQL*Plus, as that would load the second file's commands into the block that you're calling it from.

The reason that you're not getting any output is that, as far as SQL*Plus is concerned it's all one command: the SQLPlus block. In order to get output to your log for those commands, you'll need to create it yourself, using `DBMS_OUTPUT`. You would need to include a line like the one below after each command.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows inserted');
```

However, you should note that doing this will cause your script to throw errors if it's ever called from outside of a PL/SQL block. My original solution would avoid this restriction, as it eliminates the need to use `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

---

**Original Answer**

<strike>I find it difficult to believe that the PL/SQL in the first file is executing successfully. This is because you're mixing SQL*Plus commands with PL/SQL code. They are separate systems - it's like trying to use shell commands natively in a programming language. You should be getting `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting...` from the first file.</strike>

SQL*Plus doesn't have conditionals, so, in order to keep the PL/SQL and SQLPlus commands seperate, you'd need to fake it somewhat. I'd suggest putting the file name into a substitution variable, then using that to run a file:

```
VARIABLE v_my_file_bind varchar2(100)
DECLARE
 ...
BEGIN
IF ...
 ...
   :v_my_file_bind := 'D:\EMPTY_FILE.sql';
ELSE  
   :v_my_file_bind := 'D:\DM_FIX.sql';
END IF;
END;
/
COLUMN v_my_file_column new_value my_file_substitution noprint
SELECT :v_my_file_bind v_my_file_column from dual;
@&&my_file_substitution
```

Comment: SQL*Plus does allow what the OP is doing; the `@` causes the contents of the `DM_FIX.sql` file to be included in the PL/SQL script before it is parsed and executed. Not saying it's a great idea, but it's valid. (I've just verified that for my own sanity, but turns out [I've shown this before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21112230/266304)).

Comment: @Alex Poole: Huh. I did not know that. Though, even in that case, an error should have occurred, since the second block contains DDL.

Comment: True, it wouldn't understand the `truncate`, but the OP is only running the first file (`DM_FIX.sql`) and that only has DML... I think... it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @Alex Poole: Right again. Apparently my reading comprehension leaves something to be desired today.

Answer (score 0):

To show count of modified rows in PL/SQL, use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`:

```
begin
  insert into my_table ...
  select ...
  from ...;

  dbms_output.put_line('Rows inserted: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
  commit;
end;
/
```

Remember, that `SQL%ROWCOUNT` variable will reset to 0 after commit.
Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm